# Textview alignment in Android 4.0

Tags: android, fonts, textview, alignment, arabic

I am finding difficulty in aligning the text inside a textview which is in arabic font.The text is being hidden when I give a right gravity. I tried setting the padding and margin to the textview. But nothing seems to be working. It mainly happens in Android 4.0.

Please see the screenshot of the layout in Android 4.0 and Android 2.2. 
[image: Android 4.0]
[image: Android 2.2]

Is it the problem with the Android version or the font or something else? Any help or suggestions appreciated.

## The xml code is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/line_num"
            android:layout_width="22dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15dip" >
        </TextView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/line_versearab"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="16dp"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="arab"
                android:textColor="#F5F1F1"
                android:textSize="24dip" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/line_versemalayalam"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Malayalam"
                 android:gravity="left"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:textColor="#F5F1F1"
                android:textSize="18dip" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

=====

NB: The textview under consideration is with the id "line_versearab". There is another text view underneath the arabic text in the listviewrow. But I cropped it  as it is unnecessary.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check.

Comment: Please help in this regard.

Comment: what about param `ellipsize : start ` ?

Comment: I've tried that, but it didn't work. Will that be an issue with the typeface?